# video issues with slideshow plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

i am doing a task where i have to implement five full screen background videos into some slider.

Blocks alone work perfectly well, i used vide.js and then later i even found this pure css solution - http://jsfiddle.net/L8j8oyt8/ but when i add these blocks into slider plugin (tried both bxslider and flex slider), the videos just wont play. I see video elements in DOM and everything but it just won't work.

I also have something strangely working here - http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/1/

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>
    <video autoplay loop controls>
        <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</li>
<li>
    <video autoplay loop controls>
        <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</li>
<li>
    <video autoplay loop controls>
        <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>    
</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions? I am thinking of wrapping all the separate blocks with videos in 1 wrapper and simply 'emulate' the slider effect with jquery scrollTo()

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found one method that worked so far.

What i did was:

Created a video element without source but background image as a fallback.

Initialised slideshow (flexslider, because bxslider has some issues with freezing completely when swiped on tablets) and after initialisation appending source to each video element.
Worked without problems.

Still found no reason why videos wont play when you predefine source before initialising slider.